# ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames - smooth transition between positions in WinRT

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I would like to use **ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames** to animate one of my control in winrt. Control should move from Margin="0,0,-500,0" to Margin="0,0,0,0" during some time. I have following code. It almost works, but everything is happened at once and no animation or smooth transition is seen.

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NameOfControl" 
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                                   Duration="00:00:00.5">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,0,-500,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.5">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,0,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

- Do you have any clue why it does not work please?
- Do you have another way
  how to move control from outside of some panel to its default
  position? In my opinion, using of the margin is some type of hack for it.

Comment: I'm not a WinRT expert, but this is what I would try: instead of animating the `Margin`, place your control inside a `Canvas` and animate `Canvas.Left` using a `DoubleAnimation`. You can find an example in Charles Petzold's article ["Animating Attached Properties"](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/09/080231.html). All necessary classes seem to be available in WinRT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found it. Look this code. (it moves control 100 points down and 100 points to the right)

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="100"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextBlock1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="100"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

But you can't forget to add this code to control you would like to move.

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Text="SomeText">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with with `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` & `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` u are using, it does not animate the values but instead it set the value as whole at the mentioned key frame time,

In order to animate properties like Margin, Padding etc. use `ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames`  with `SplineThicknessKeyFrame` instead, this will animate the values in a smoother transition

sample for you

```
<ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NameOfControl" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" 
                               Duration="00:00:00.5">
    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,0,-500,0" />
    <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="0,0,0,0" />
</ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**WinRT alternative**

since you are using the concerned element to bring it into the view using the right margin

I attempted to create a sample which will mimic the similar behavior using double animation

```
    <Rectangle Fill="Red"
               Width="10"
               Height="10"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="translate"
                                         From="500" 
                                         To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```

also it is not a wise idea to animate margin property as it also force layout to be done again

Comment: `ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames` unfortunately is not available under WinRT.

Comment: II wrote the answer as WPF as it was not clear from the question's title or description until I saw a small tag for winrt after you've mentioned here. apologies for the same. I've updated my answer for an alternative approach for WinRT

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the duration and the keyFrame you set in your code is too less and thats why there is no transition felt by you. please increase the duration and keyframe and let me know the results.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried longer time as well, but it behaves in the same manner.